# Refreshing one section of a page using Ajax context

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, refresh

I'm trying to refresh just one part of my page when a user clicks a 'clear' button, currently I'm using a bit of code I hacked off another answer I found on here:

```
$('.clear').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      context: document.body,
      success: function (s, x) {
        $(this).html(s);
      }
    });
});
```

This reloads the whole document body, how do I target a particular div or class?

```
  context: document.body.somediv?
```

Comment: just use any javascript/jquery method which returns a DOM node as: `context: document.getElementById('divId')` or less cross browser `window.divId`

Comment: Romjin's answer was good but I've actually ended up using your method since it does exactly what I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) about the `context` option:

> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By
>   default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings
>   used in the call ($.ajaxSettings merged with the settings passed to
>   $.ajax). For example, specifying a DOM element as the context will
>   make that the context for the complete callback of a request, like so:
>
> ```
> $.ajax({
>   url: "test.html",
>   context: document.body
> }).done(function() {
>   $( this ).addClass( "done" );
> });
> ```

So, the `context` option is to set the scope of the `this` object in the callback functions. By default it is the ajax object, with the current configuration:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ""
}).done(function(){
    console.log(this); 
    // logs: { url: "", type: "GET", etc... }
    // 
});
```

If you wish to target a specific section to load the response in, you can just use jQuery to find the element and put the response in that element, `context` is not relevant for you:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "",
}).success(function(data){
  // data is your response
  $(".some-element").html(data);
});
```

However, you can use `context` to make the configuration a bit easier to understand, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "",
  context: $(".some-element")
}).success(function(data){
  $(this).html(data);
  // $(this) refers to the context object, in this case $(".some-element")
});
```

If you now want your ajax response to be loaded somewhere else on the page, you just have to change the selector on the `context` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 success: function (s, x) {
    $('#yourdiv').html(s);//yourdiv is id of div u want to update
    }
```

Can also access div by its class like

```
$('.classOfDiv')
```

Have u tried using of context

```
context: {div:$('#yourdiv')}
```

In success

```
this.div.html(s);
```

Comment: OP was asking for the use of context

Comment: just check $.ajax DOC or see quotes in Justus Romijn's answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use DIV id or class name to target a particular div element.

```
<div id="div1" class="class1">
    <div id="div2" class="class2">
    </div>
</div>


$('#div2').html(your-text); // using ID

$('.class2').html(your-text); // using Class
```

Comment: what I was asking was how to target a particular class within ajax

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want that ajax output reflect on a particular div, Please make sure that div has Id or class so we can easily trace that on DOM.
Suppose that div has class `content-output` then following script will work for you.

```
$('.clear').click(function () {
$.ajax({
url: "",
success: function (s, x) {
$('.content-output').html(s);
}
});
});
```

Comment: What is purpose of `context: document.body` here?

Comment: It is not required for this scenario, so we can escape it because we are specifying  div

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly,you can simply call .load() from a click event and pass it the href of the link:

```
HTML:

<a class="link" href="page.php?id=10">Click Here<a>

JS:

$(".link").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#text").load($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

[see the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ueucL/99/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.clear').click(function () {
$.ajax({
url: "",
//context: document.body,  //you don't need a context
success: function (s, x) {
$(.myClass).html(s);       
//now the target is class myClass or you can use 
//#myID if you want to have an id as target
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load only particular div via Ajax then use jquery **load** event like this

```
//clear button click event
$('.clear').click(function () {

  // load ajax response inside result id (html element)
  $( "#result" ).load( "URL" );

});
```

If you to perform some kind of action then add function inside load event like this

```
$( "#result" ).load( "URL", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```