# Refreshing a page using checkbox, jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I got a checkbox on a webpage which switches between different sets of jquery code. Here is the html:

```
          ... 
        <div class="flip_switch">
          <input type="checkbox" name="flip_switch" class="flip_switch-checkbox" id="myflip_switch" checked ="checked">
          <label class="flip_switch-label" for="myflip_switch">
            <span class="flip_switch-inner"></span>
            <span class="flip_switch-switch"></span>
          </label> 
          </div>
        </div>  
        <p class = "wln_title">Word Learning 1</p>
      </div>
    <div class="wln_container">     
      <div id="wln_col1" class="wln_items">                                            
        <p class="word_learn">1<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e01">the</span>         คำนำหน้านามเจาะจง </span></p>
        <p class="word_learn">2<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e02">and</span>       และ </span></p>
        <p class="word_learn">3<span class="color_up audio" id="b1e03">of</span>         ของ </span></p>
        ...
```

and the jquery fragment:

```
    jQuery('input.flip_switch-checkbox').on("click", function () {
       var checked = jQuery("div.flip_switch  input#myflip_switch").is(':checked');
        if(checked) {
        (listen to audio of all words in sequence ...)
        } else {
        (listen to audio of individually selected words ...)
        }
        });
```

The idea is that the user can listen to the audio of the words sequentially thru the whole set on the page or can switch to selecting individual words to listen to. The problem is that the switch between the 2 jquery states only works on page refresh. I've tried to do a partial page refresh using AJAX following the suggestions here: [Refreshing one section of a page using Ajax context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349955/refreshing-one-section-of-a-page-using-ajax-context) (brief alias for links?)
specifically:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "",
      context: jQuery("div.wln_container")
    }).success(function(data){
      jQuery(this).html(data);
      // jQuery(this) refers to the context object, in this case jQuery(".some-element")
    });
```

placing it before the other jquery code. All that happens is that the whole page is briefly displayed then it hangs. I've looked elsewhere and tried the jQuery load() method but I can't get anything that works. I'm obviously missing some crucial point here.

Comment: Are you running this last jquery code when checkbox clicked?

Comment: Yes the jquery code for the audio is running before the chcekbox is clicked